# How to get multiple messages in one handler

Tags: android

I have 2 messages sent to the handler mHandler(). I have `msg.what =0`and `msg.what =1`. I need to retrieve both messages and their objects so that i can get my image and username. Help please

```
    @Override
    public void onComplete(final JSONObject response, Object state) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.obj = response;
                    msg.what = 0;
                    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    new Thread(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(response.has("figureurl")){
                                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                                try {
                                    bitmap = Util.getbitmap(response.getString("figureurl_qq_2"));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {

                                }
                                Message msg = new Message();
                                msg.obj = bitmap;
                                msg.what = 1;
                                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                            }
                        }

                    }.start();
                }
            };
              mTencent.requestAsync(Constants.GRAPH_SIMPLE_USER_INFO, null,
                        Constants.HTTP_GET, requestListener, null);
        } else {
            //mUserInfo.setText("");
            //mUserInfo.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);
            //mUserLogo.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LeftAndRightActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, "");

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            System.out.println(msg.what);
            if (msg.what == 0) {
                JSONObject response = (JSONObject) msg.obj;
                if (response.has("nickname")) {
                    try {
                        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LeftAndRightActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra(USER_NAME, response.getString("nickname"));
                        startActivity(i);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }if(msg.what == 1){
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LeftAndRightActivity.class);
                Bitmap b = (Bitmap)msg.obj;
                ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
                i.putExtra(BYTE_ARRAY, bs.toByteArray());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }

    };
```

Comment: Do you want to retrieve both objects at the same time?

Comment: yes. I want to retrieve both at the same time.

Comment: It is not possible. Messages are processed sequentially. What you can do is to wrap all the information inside an object, a JSONObject for instance and use the same msg.what value

Comment: When you get the first message store its content into another object and when you get second you will have both first(stored) and second object contents.

Comment: Is it possible to store 2 different object inside 1 message?

Comment: first of all dont use new Message, use Message.obtain or Handler.obtainMessage